# How to calculate the time complexity of back tracking algorithm

Tags: c, algorithm, time-complexity

Have used this program, How to calculate the time complexity of a backtracking algo?

```
/*
  Function to print permutations of string    This function takes three parameters:
  1. String
  2. Starting index of the string
  3. Ending index of the string.
*/ 
void swap (char *x, char *y)
{
  char temp;
  temp = *x;
  *x = *y;
  *y = temp;
}

void permute(char *a, int i, int n)
{  
  int j;

  if (i == n)
    printf("%s\n", a);
  else
  {
    for (j = i; j <= n; j++)
    {
      swap((a+i), (a+j));
      permute(a, i+1, n);
      swap((a+i), (a+j)); //backtrack
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 12):

Each `permute(a,i,n)` causes `n-i` calls to `permute(a,i+1,n)`

Thus, when `i == 0` there are `n` calls, when `i == 1` there are `n-1` calls... when `i == n-1` there is one call.

You can find from this a recursive formula for number of iterations: 

`T(1) = 1` [base] ; and `T(n) = n * T(n-1)` [step]

Resulting in total of `T(n) = n * T(n-1) = n * (n-1) * T(n-2) = .... = n * (n-1) * ... * 1 = n!`

**EDIT: [small correction]:** since the condition in the for loop is `j <= n` [and not `j < n`], each `permute()` is actually invoking `n-i+1` times `permute(a,i+1,n)`, resulting in T(n) = `(n+1) * T(n-1)` [step] and `T(0) = 1` [base], which later leads to `T(n) = (n+1) * n * ... * 1 = (n+1)!`. 

However, it seems to be an implementation bug more then a feature :\

Comment: as a sidenote, since there's `n!` permutations of `n` objects, it would be quite a surprise if OP's algo has any other complexity.

Answer (score 0):

A simple intuition is that there will be n! permutation and you have to generate all of them. Therefore, your time complexity will be at least n! as you will have to traverse through all n! in order to generate all of them.
Thus, the time complexity is O(n!).